# Grouping the Laravel Api Resources

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-5.5, jsonapi-resources

I'm trying to group the json response in Laravel 5.5

My table is following

```
+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------- 
--------------------------------------------------+
| year | month | people                                                                                                  
|
+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------- 
--------------------------------------------------+

| 2017 |    3 | 松本 知実                                                                                               
|
| 2016 |    12 | 中島 春香,中津川 充,村山 裕樹,杉山 翼,中島 春香,木村 稔                                                 
|
| 2017 |     3 | 桐山 裕太,吉本 稔,藤本 稔                                                                               
|
| 2015 |     3 | 喜嶋 学,若松 康弘,鈴木 直子,宮沢 幹                                                                     
|
| 2017 |    11 | 大垣 晃,江古田 里佳,野村 康弘,中村 美加子,喜嶋 裕太                                                     
|
| 2016 |     6 | 中島 春香,中津川 充,村山 裕樹,杉山 翼,中島 春香,木村 稔                                                       
|
| 2015 |    11 | 野村 英樹,工藤 智也,山本 七夏,青田 舞                                                                   
|
```

and i wanna get the following json response

```
"2015" : {
    "3" : {
        "people" : "喜嶋 学,若松 康弘,鈴木 直子,宮沢 幹"
    },
    "11" : {
        "people" : "野村 英樹,工藤 智也,山本 七夏,青田 舞"
    },
},
"2016" : {
    "6" : {
        "people" : "中島 春香,中津川 充,村山 裕樹,杉山 翼,中島 春香,木村 稔"
    },
    "12" : {
        "people" : "中島 春香,中津川 充,村山 裕樹,杉山 翼,中島 春香,木村 稔"
    },
},
"2017" : {
    "3" : {
        [
            "people" : "松本 知実",
            "people" : "桐山 裕太,吉本 稔,藤本 稔",
        ]
    },
    "11" : {
        "people" : "大垣 晃,江古田 里佳,野村 康弘,中村 美加子,喜嶋 裕太"
    },
}
```

But i can't group the people data by same year and same months...
My code is here.

My Controller

```
class PublicationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $publications = Publication::orderBy('year', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('month', 'DESC')
            ->get();
        return PublicationResource::collection($publications);
    }
}
```

and My Resource

```
class PublicationResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            $this->year => [
                $this->month => [
                    'people' => $this->people,
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

But now in my code, the response is following.

```
"2017": {
    "11": {
        "people": "大垣 晃,江古田 里佳,野村 康弘,中村 美加子,喜嶋 裕太"
    }
},
"2017": {
    "3": {
        "people": "松本 知実"
    }
},
"2017": {
    "3": {
        "people": "桐山 裕太,吉本 稔,藤本 稔"
    }
},
"2016": {
    "12": {
        "people": "中島 春香,中津川 充,村山 裕樹,杉山 翼,中島 春香,木村 稔"
    }
},
"2016": {
    "6": {
        "people": "中島 春香,中津川 充,村山 裕樹,杉山 翼,中島 春香,木村 稔"
    }
},
"2015": {
    "11": {
        "people": "野村 英樹,工藤 智也,山本 七夏,青田 舞"
    }
},
"2015": {
    "3": {
        "people": "喜嶋 学,若松 康弘,鈴木 直子,宮沢 幹"
    }
},
```

I wanna group my data by same year and same months.

How should i change my code?

I'm sorry I'm a newer of laravel.
so please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your controller to

```
class PublicationController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $publications = Publication::orderBy('year', 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('month', 'DESC')
        ->get();
    return $publications->groupBy('year');
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i think, in this way, i can't choose which columns return or not, right?
I want to select columns i return.

If you know how to do, please tell me.

Comment: to choose the columns you want, select them from db via `Model::select('column')->get();`, this will still return collections which you can use `groupBy()` later on

Comment: Thank you

In this way, i cannot change the structure of json response, right?

For example,

`
    '2014' => [
        'Jan' => [
            'people' => [ 'Mr.Apple', 'Ms. Orange']
        ]
    ]
`

Like this

Comment: you can do this while querying the db, and another way to to use `collection->toArray()` then change whatever you need